# How to manage age-gate related logic, on alcohol and drink recipe pages?

Tags: javascript, amp-html

I really like AMP pages and the experience it brings and I am in the process of implementing on pages containing drink recipes. The problem is that such pages  must be gated with a form that requires age verification. In order to verify the users age, javascript needs to evaluate the input values and hide the lightbox containing the form. But since AMP pages does not allow custom javascript code, this becomes difficult.

Now, the logic can be moved to serverside but then all pages will be parsed with a age-gate...consequently all recipe pages will display the age-gate, regardless of its content.

Do anyone have any suggestion on how to tackle this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the only way to do this will be to put in a feature request for it on github. I have been thinking about this for the past two days and I can't think of a way to implement it without a bit of Javascript or some sort of landing page.

Comment: Never mind, just took a look at their [Roadmap](https://www.ampproject.org/roadmap/) and it looks like they might have something out later this year that could accomplish what you wanted to do.

Comment: I tried solving this with an iFrame but it turned out to be very difficult and calls to parent frame were blocked. I hope they provide a way to solve this.

Comment: Well, it still wouldn't hurt to put in a request on github and see what they say. They might have some sort of temporary solution for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

With assistance from authors / contributors, I have been able to solve this issue. Check out the thread here to understand how to resolve it:

https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/4725

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way you can use JS in AMP pages.

Here's the [statement from AMP tech lead](https://www.ampproject.org/how-it-works/):

> One thing we realized early on is that many performance issues are
>   caused by the integration of multiple JavaScript libraries, tools,
>   embeds, etc. into a page. This isn’t saying that JavaScript
>   immediately leads to bad performance, but once arbitrary JavaScript is
>   in play, most bets are off because anything could happen at any time
>   and it is hard to make any type of performance guarantee. **With this in
>   mind we made the tough decision that AMP HTML documents would not
>   include any author-written JavaScript, nor any third-party scripts.**